# I use the below code to click photo in android phone but the captured image doesn't get saved in gallery

Tags: android, photo, image-gallery

I use the below code to click photo in android phone but the captured image doesn't get saved in gallery. I'm new to android app development.Please verify this code and help me out.

package project.example.rivaa;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.VideoView;


public class PhotoIntentActivity extends Activity {
     static String vid;
    private static final int ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B = 1;

    private static final String BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY = "viewbitmap";
    private static final String IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY = "imageviewvisibility";
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private Bitmap mImageBitmap;


    private String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    private static final String PNG_FILE_PREFIX = "IMG_";
    private static final String PNG_FILE_SUFFIX = ".png";

    private AlbumStorageDirFactory mAlbumStorageDirFactory = null;


    /* Photo album for this application */
    private String getAlbumName() {
        return getString(R.string.album_name);
    }


    private File getAlbumDir() {
        File storageDir = null;

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {

            storageDir = mAlbumStorageDirFactory.getAlbumStorageDir(getAlbumName());

            if (storageDir != null) {
                if (! storageDir.mkdirs()) {
                    if (! storageDir.exists()){
                        Log.d("CameraSample", "failed to create directory");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), "External storage is not mounted READ/WRITE.");
        }

        return storageDir;
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name

        String imageFileName = PNG_FILE_PREFIX +vid+ "_";
        File albumF = getAlbumDir();
        File imageF = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, PNG_FILE_SUFFIX, albumF);
        return imageF;
    }

    private File setUpPhotoFile() throws IOException {

        File f = createImageFile();
        mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();

        return f;
    }

    private void setPic() {

        /* There isn't enough memory to open up more than a couple camera photos */
        /* So pre-scale the target bitmap into which the file is decoded */

        /* Get the size of the ImageView */
        int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
        int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

        /* Get the size of the image */
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        /* Figure out which way needs to be reduced less */
        int scaleFactor = 1;
        if ((targetW > 0) || (targetH > 0)) {
            scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH); 
        }

        /* Set bitmap options to scale the image decode target */
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        /* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

        /* Associate the Bitmap to the ImageView */
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void galleryAddPic() {
            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
            File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
            this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        switch(actionCode) {
        case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B:
            File f = null;

            try {
                f = setUpPhotoFile();
                mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                f = null;
                mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;          
        } // switch

        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
    }




    private void handleBigCameraPhoto() {

        if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null) {
            setPic();
            galleryAddPic();
            mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
        }

    }



    Button.OnClickListener mTakePicOnClickListener = 
        new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent(ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B);
        }
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photointentactivity);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        mImageBitmap = null;


        Button picBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIntend);
        setBtnListenerOrDisable( 
                picBtn, 
                mTakePicOnClickListener,
                MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
        );



        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
            mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new FroyoAlbumDirFactory();
        } else {
            mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new BaseAlbumDirFactory();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                handleBigCameraPhoto();
                Intent fd= new Intent("project.example.rivaa.OTP");
                  startActivity(fd);
            }
            break;
        } // ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B


        } // switch
    }

    // Some lifecycle callbacks so that the image can survive orientation change
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY, mImageBitmap);

        outState.putBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY, (mImageBitmap != null) );

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mImageBitmap = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY);

        mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
        mImageView.setVisibility(
                savedInstanceState.getBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY) ? 
                        ImageView.VISIBLE : ImageView.INVISIBLE
        );

    }

    /**
     * Indicates whether the specified action can be used as an intent. This
     * method queries the package manager for installed packages that can
     * respond to an intent with the specified action. If no suitable package is
     * found, this method returns false.
     * http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/can-i-use-this-intent.html
     *
     * @param context The application's environment.
     * @param action The Intent action to check for availability.
     *
     * @return True if an Intent with the specified action can be sent and
     *         responded to, false otherwise.
     */
    public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) {
        final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        List<ResolveInfo> list =
            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        return list.size() > 0;
    }

    private void setBtnListenerOrDisable( 
            Button btn, 
            Button.OnClickListener onClickListener,
            String intentName
    ) {
        if (isIntentAvailable(this, intentName)) {
            btn.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);            
        } else {
            btn.setText( 
                getText(R.string.cannot).toString() + " " + btn.getText());
            btn.setClickable(false);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What you want to do exactly its not clear from your question,can you please be specific?

Answer (score 0):

Your galleryAddPic() method doesn´t work? What if You try it like this:

```
  String[] path = { mCurrentPhotoPath };
  String[] type = {"image/jpeg"};
  MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, path, type, null);
```

it is maybe not the solution, but to long for a comment..the type depends on what type You saved.